# Make a DIV part of an image, or how to place two divs next to each other and automatically put them below each other

Tags: css, image, html

I'm trying to create a div which is part of an image. It will automatically move if the image will be moved (for example, the browser size has become smaller, and the image will move. The div will follow the image). However, I have no idea how to do that. I tried the following method:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="2.jpg">
    <img src="1.jpg">
    <div class="play1" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px">Content</div>
</div>
```

*Note: The wrapper has 'relative' as position style*

I thought: In case this is impossible, I could create two divs with the image as background. So, each image has it's own div. But, how would I place those two divs next to eachother, and make them "split" if the browser gets smaller. I know how to place two divs next to each other, but how would I make it possible that if, the browser gets smaller, the second image will move below the first image.

p/s For the off-topic voters: I do not have a piece of code for my second question, because I simply have absolutely no clue how I would do that. I could paste a piece of code where two divs are next to each other, but that's all.

Comment: Use media queries in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Ed Cottrell's help, I managed to do exactly what I wanted. To place the two divs next to each other, I used

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 1):

`float` is perfect for this. For each div in question, give it the style `float:left;` (assuming you want the first one to line up to the left) or `float:right;` (if you want the first one to line up to the right). The divs will be side-by-side normally, but the second one will get bumped down if they don't both fit.

Comment: It works, thanks. However, it doesn't seem to center anymore as it's parent defined (margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 top: 100px;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 text-align: center;
 overflow:hidden;
)

And also, how would I add a little space between the two divs?

Comment: There isn't any centering in the code you posted above, so I'm not sure what you are trying to center. If you can post additional code, I might be able to help you with this. It might be as simple as putting the `div`s or `img`s (or whatever) inside a `<div style="text-align:center">` container.

Comment: @EdCottrell 
This parent is centered in the screen with the following code. It's centered on the top of 100px:
`.parent{
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 top: 100px;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 text-align: center;
 overflow:hidden;
}` 

`<div class="parent">
  <div class="image1">
  </div>
  <div class="image2">
  </div>
 </div>`

`.image1{
 background-image: url('1.jpg');
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 float: left;
}

.image2{
 background-image: url('2.jpg');
 width: 200x;
 height: 200px;
 float:left;
}`

Comment: Just use this HTML instead of what you have (but keep the CSS): `<div class="parent"> <div style="text-align:center"> <div class="image1"> </div> <div class="image2"> </div> </div> </div>`.

Comment: @EdCottrell Doesn't seem to work. it does seem to work with text

Comment: Post a jsfiddle or some other fiddle that people can play with, please. It's hard to diagnose problems without seeing the patient. :)

Comment: I solved it by using `display: inline-block;`! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/QNEmF/12/

**CSS:**

```
 @media all and (max-width:500px){
         #sidebar, #content { float:none; width:100%; }
  }
```

First make them `float` when screen(browser) size will get to 500px or lower. they'll switch to above css, thus stacked one above the other.